# Faster method to determine subset of rows of matrix containing particular entry

Tags: python, list, algorithm, performance, optimization

I am looking for a time-efficient solution to the below problem that exploits the fact that I want to perform a certain operation many times over. I have two methods implemented below, and I observe that one of them is significantly faster. I am wondering if there is a more efficient alternative to both methods.

**Input**: Matrix mat of dimension m*n populated with nonnegative integers (0 <= each integer <= b). Also given p nonnegative integers q<sub>1</sub>, q<sub>2</sub>, ..., q<sub>p</sub> (each <= b) and vectors v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, ..., v<sub>p</sub>. Each entry of v<sub>j</sub> contains d row indices of mat.

I am interested in cases where m, p, and d are large (~10<sup>6</sup>), n is small (~10), and b is small (~100).

**Output**: For each pair (v<sub>j</sub>,q<sub>j</sub>), return the sub-list of rows of mat among v<sub>j</sub>[0], v<sub>j</sub>[1], ..., v<sub>j</sub>[d-1] that contain the integer q<sub>j</sub>.

**My approach**: Because p can be large, I preprocessed mat to determine if each row contains any of the numbers between 0 and b. Then, I went through the vectors v<sub>j</sub> to determine if the rows of mat defined by their entries contained q<sub>j</sub>. I tried two different approaches to storing whether each row of mat contains any integer between 0 and b. To my surprise, I found that Method 1 performs significantly faster than Method 2.

**Question**: I am wondering if there is a better (practical) way to preprocess mat so that the operations for each pair (v<sub>j</sub>,q<sub>j</sub>) are as fast as possible.

Edit: Defining a tmp variable as tmp = isPresent[qs[j]] and iterating through the elements of tmp yielded a faster solution, but I'm hoping I can do something even faster.

Note: Ordering of elements in result is not important.

```
# Python code

import random
import numpy
import time

m = 1000000 # number of rows of mat
n = 10 # number of columns of mat
b = 255 # upper bound on entries of mat
d = 10000 # dimension of vec (containing row indices of mat)
p = 100 # number of vecs

# random specification of mat
# mat, vec, and q will be inputs from another part of the project
mat = []
for i in range(m):
    tmp = (numpy.random.permutation(b+1))[0:n]
    mat.append(tmp)

# random specification of vec and q
vecs = []
qs = []
for i in range(p):
    qs.append(random.randrange(0,b+1,1))
    vecs.append((numpy.random.permutation(m))[0:d])


# METHOD 1

# store the rows where each integer occurs
# not too worried about time taken by this step
isPresent = [[False]*m for i in range(b+1)]
for i in range(m):
    for j in mat[i]:
        isPresent[j][i] = True

# mainly care about reducing time from hereon
time1 = 0.0
for j in range(p):
    st1 = time.time()
    result1 = []
    for i in vecs[j]:
        if isPresent[qs[j]][i]:
            result1.append(i)
    time1 += time.time() - st1


# METHOD 2

# store the rows where each integer occurs
# not too worried about time taken by this step
isPresent = [[False]*(b+1) for i in range(m)]
for i in range(m):
    for j in mat[i]:
        isPresent[i][j] = True

# mainly care about reducing time from hereon
time2 = 0.0
for j in range(p):
    st2 = time.time()
    result2 = []
    for i in vecs[j]:
        if isPresent[i][qs[j]]:
            result2.append(i)
    time2 += time.time() - st2


print('time1: ',time1,'  time2: ',time2)
```

Note: I observe time1 = 0.46 seconds and time2 = 0.69 seconds on my laptop

Comment: I suspect this a caching issue.  Your Method 1 seems like it might have better locality of access.  I don't know how practical it is in Python to pack the `isPresent` flags into 1 bit per flag ?

Comment: Is the order of the elements in `result` important? If yes, is it a partial or a total ordering?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Yes, there is a much better way to compute that using numpy. However, please note that there is a 2D random memory indirection pattern which is generally slow and known to be difficult to optimize.

**Useful information:**
Random memory accesses are slow. Indeed, it is difficult for the processor to predict memory address to fetch and thus reduce the latency of the memory. This is not too bad as long as data fit in the caches and are reused several times. Random memory accesses done over a huge memory area are *much slower* and should be avoided like the plague (when it is possible).

**Analysis:**
Both methods do a random memory indirections when executing the expressions `isPresent[qs[j]][i]` and `isPresent[i][qs[j]]`.
Such indirections are slow. But the method 2 is slower since the average distance between fetched address tends to be much bigger than the method 1 causing an effect called *cache thrashing*.

**Faster solution:** Numpy can be used to strongly increase the performance of the first method (thanks to "vectorized" native methods).
Indeed, this method uses plain python loops that are generally very slow and recomputes `isPresent[qs[j]]` several times.
Here is the faster implementation:

```
# Assume vecs is a list of np.arrray rather than a list of list

isPresent = [numpy.array([False]*m) for i in range(b+1)]
for i in range(m):
    for j in mat[i]:
        isPresent[j][i] = True

time3 = 0.0
for j in range(p):
    st3 = time.time()
    tmp = isPresent[qs[j]]
    result3 = numpy.extract(tmp[vecs[j]], vecs[j])
    time3 += time.time() - st3
```

**Performance results:**

```
time1:  0.165357
time2:  0.309095
time3:  0.007201
```

The new version is 23 times faster than the first method and 43 times faster than the second.

Note that one can do this significantly faster by computing the `j`-loop in parallel, but this is a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks. I did define a similar variable as "tmp" earlier today, and it led to a significant speed-up. Within my application, it seems like using numpy arrays as in your solution makes things significantly (4x) slower.